# What does a go program crash without a stacktrace mean?

Tags: go, cgo

I am running a go program in a kubernetes pod, and there is `cgo` usage in the app. The pod crashes, sometimes with a traceback, sometimes without.

When there is a traceback, it points to GC tasks:

```
error: bad use of bucket.mp
error: non in-use span in unswept list
morestack on g0
error: non in-use span in unswept list
error: span set block with unpopped elements found in reset
```

Setting `GODEBUG=cgocheck=2` (slow, strict validity checks on pointer passing from go->c) does not lead to catching invalid pointer passing. Setting `GODEBUG=invalidptr=0` to prevent the garbage collector from panic'ing on invalid pointers leads to the app exclusively crashing without a stack trace.

It seems I have 2 problems -- the first is invalid pointers (from somewhere) ending up in go's GC checks. This can be mitigated while the other problems are investigated with `GODEBUG=invalidptr=0`. What does it mean when a go program crashes without a stack trace? Could go code cause this, or does this indicate a problem in the c code?

Edit (additional data):

These crashes only happen in scratch pod (using musl compiler), and happen within a matter of minutes. If I compile the binary using the default CC and run in a debian container in the pod, the program is able to run without crashing (has been the case for 3 hours).

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the question to ask on SO. Consider posting a message to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts) which is read by the Go developers. While doing so please be sure to include the version of Go used to build your program, and the GOOS (though from mentioning of "pod" I assume it's `linux`) and the GOARCH.

Comment: The `cgocheck=2` still can't prevent C code from misusing a pointer which was validly passed in, which I think is the most likely scenario here. There's no way for the `cgocheck` to validate that a pointer was stored after the function returned, specifically the rule: `"C code may not keep a copy of a Go pointer after the call returns. This includes the _GoString_ type, which, as noted above, includes a Go pointer; _GoString_ values may not be retained by C code."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I joined the gopher slack and posted this stack overflow link. I was pointed to the fact that `musl` is not 100% compatible as a c compiler in the go toolchain. Building a statically linked binary with the default c compiler solved all crashes.